# woocomerce ¿childtheme de storefront o tema propio adaptado?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy creando una tienda de repostería con wordpress y woocommerce.
Lo primero que hice fue crear un tema propio totalmente personalizado desde cero. Una vez creado, he instalado el plugin de woocomerce y me he encontrado con una posibilidad que desconocía antes de empezar: instalar storefront y crear a partir de este un childtheme también personalizado.
He optado por adaptar la tienda a mi propio tema y olvidarme de storefront y los childthemes. Por el momento parece sencillo adaptar los templates pero me surgen varias dudas:

¿es buena praxis?
¿existe o puede existir en el futuro algún inveniente grave por hacer esto?
¿voy a perder funcionalidades?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre y cuando trabajes correctamente tu tema no deberia haber problema, no perderas funcionalidades pero hay cosas que debes hacer como darle soporte en functions, te recomiendo usar un tema de inicio (Started Theme) como el tema de Underscore https://underscores.me/ aqui tendras un tema en blanco que puedes adaptar a tus necesidades sin preocuparte de las actualizaciones.

Usar un child-theme tampoco es problema, pero personalmente siempre prefiero usar un tema propio.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas un tema hijo de storefront, ten en cuenta que la nueva hoja de estilos del tema hijo no se tiene en cuenta para los estilos, tendras que manipular la hoja original

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/